# How should I use correctly Partial and Record Utility types, on a typescript data building function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
type CatName = "Silvester" | "boris" | "mordred";
interface CatInfo {
  age: number;
  breed: string;
}

public static async buildMyData(): Promise<Record<CatName, CatInfo>> {

  let allCats: Partial<Record<CatName, CatInfo>> =
    {};
    // collecting async all Cats Info
  await Promise.all(
    ...
      let catInfo = await someInfo();
      allCats[catName] = catInfo;
    ...
  );

  return allCats;
}
```

I will get these errors:

Type 'Partial<Record<CatName, CatInfo>>' is not assignable to type 'Record<CatName, CatInfo>'.

Types of property 'Silvester' are incompatible.
Type 'CatInfo | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CatInfo'.

So It complains because  it doesn't know if allCats will be fulfilled and a complete
Record<CatName, CatInfo>

What do you recommend as a better approach here?

I know I can skip the errors above by casting the return variable like:

```
return allCats as Record<CatName, CatInfo>
```

or changing the return type

```
public static async buildMyData(): Promise<PartialRecord<<CatName, CatInfo>>>
```

But maybe there's a better way for this?

Answer (score 1):

So the issue here is that you expect the result of some operation inside your Promise to fulfill the requirement of *Record<CatName, CatInfo>*, but you have no way to guarantee it without use a type assertion or otherwise giving up and typing the result as a partial record?

First, if there is *any* chance that the result could be Partial, then just go with the Partial and don't try to fake it.  Type assertions should be used as sparingly as possible.

Unfortunately, type assertions are unavoidable.  So if you're 100% sure that the result will comply with *Record<CatName, CatInfo>* then go for it.

A lot of times, there is a gray area.  Where I know now that my operation will comply and making the assertion is safe, but it is possible that somebody could change a type definition in the future that would cause my assertion to be invalid.  For example, if at some point a developer added a fourth *CatName*, but no fourth Promise was added to the *Promise.all* call to accommodate the change.

When these cases are possible, or before I blindly add a blanket type assertion.  I try to base my return type on what's actually being returned from the underlying functions.

```
async buildMyData(): Promise<Record<CatName, CatInfo>> {

    const promiseBoris = await this.requestCat('boris');
    const promiseSilvester = await this.requestCat('Silvester');
    const promiseMordred = await this.requestCat('mordred');
    const promiseAllResult = await Promise.all([promiseBoris, promiseSilvester, promiseMordred]);
    const res = promiseAllResult
        .reduce(
            (acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur.catName]: cur as CatInfo}), 
            {} as { [key in typeof promiseAllResult[number]['catName']]: CatInfo });
    return res;
}

private requestCat<T extends string>(catName: T): Promise<{ catName: T } & CatInfo> {
    return new Promise<{ catName: T } & CatInfo>((resolve) => resolve({ catName, age: 1, breed: 'cat' }));
}
```

In this conveniently contrived example I still use a type assertion, but instead of assuming it will comply with Record<CatName, CatInfo>, I use the return type of the catName property in the result array to be the type of the record key.  Fortunately, those values line up with CatName so the TypeScript compiler is all good.

Had one of those requests returned a catName that wasn't one of the values from *CatName*, a possible value was added to the *CatName* type, or any other reason that result of *Promise.all* did not return an array with every possible *CatName* value, then typescript would return a compiler error, and the code would have to be adjusted to property comply.

By deriving type assertion parameters from existing type definitions you make your assertion more robust and avoid possible errors from code refactoring.